# How to send only 1 message at once after split() on inOut exchange

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Camel for a while and I'm a huge admirer of its simplicity.

**The use case**

Given this simple route:

```
from("mock:some-route")
  // split 1
  .split().method("splitterBean", "split")
  // now we have an ArrayList of n messages (let's say 10)
  .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "jms:some-thing");
```

If we assume that we have 10 messages after the split(), this route will immediately send 10 messages to the "to" endpoint. So `jms:some-thing` will receive all 10 messages at once.

**The problem**

--> Please note that the "out" endpoint is `inOut`, so we have timeouts in place when the receiver must acknowledge the message.

The application on the receiving end of `jms:some-thing` has to do quite some work for each message. As all 10 messages were written at the same time, the same timeout applies for all of them.

So we increased that timeout.

But one day, we will have 1000 messages and the timeout will again be to low.

**What i want to archieve**

I want to implement a pattern where I'll send *only 1 message at once* after the split, then sending the next *after 1 message is acknowledged* by the receiving system.

So instead of sending the 10 messages at once, I want

- Send 1 message
- Wait for the acknowledgment of that message
- Send the next
- Wait again
- And so on..

How to implement such behavior?

I looked at the documentation, but none of the EIP components seem to fulfill that need?

Thanks for any input

Comment: It depends on your split method. In your comment you have stated you are generating an arraylist. Why not generate individual messages instead so that you send 10 different messages? I.e if the arraylist is a list of strings why not generate the individual string bodies and put that as your exchange body. Then it should work as you want.

Comment: For example: .split(body(String.class).tokenize("\n")) . This code generates an exchange body per new line.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti thanks for your comment. wouldn't that be the same behavior then, that all 10 messages would be sent at once?

Comment: No, it should generate 10 separate messages. You can verify this if you add a log statement before posting to the queue.

Comment: By the way you don't need to wait for the message to consumed or done before posting the next message. You should be able to post 1000 individual messages async. It is up to the client to pick up one message at a time in its own pace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an intermediate `seda` queue with only one thread.

```
from("mock:some-route")
  .split().method("splitterBean", "split")
  .to("seda:your-seda-queue?waitForTaskToComplete=Always&timeout=0");

from("seda:your-seda-queue?waitForTaskToComplete=Always&timeout=0")
  .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "jms:some-thing");
```

By default, a seda queue will have a single consuming thread, and will block the calling thread until a consumer becomes available.  [More on seda details here](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html)

Saying that, your sending to a jms topic, which is really what you should be using to queue up your requests instead of a seda queue.  You should look into implementing this logic asynchronously, and waiting on a reply topic rather than using a timeout.

Comment: hm, thanks.. interesting.. i use seda routes, they also have timeouts (which can be disabled i have seen) - i'll look into that.. any pointers how to "implement this logic asynchronously, and waiting on a reply topic rather than using a timeout."? ;-).. to clarify: i would know how to specify and listen on a custom replyTo queue - but how/where to store my previously prepared ArrayList and know what to return in which state?  seems tricky..

Comment: you're right, you'll need to set a timeout of 0, or a negative number, and setup `waitForTaskToComplete`.
I'm not sure what your logic looks like that requires you to wait around for a response and to store your array list of queries, so I can't easily answer that question.